# Does Jira uses token based authentication?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I used jira python api to login and change the state of jira issue, or do other things. I want to know is there a token based approach that user will not have to enter password again and again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "Python" API in Jira, there is a REST API you can call from any language. If you use a library like "jira-python" you can read the docs [here](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#authentication) regarding authentication.

If you use Jira on-premise check [this documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/security-overview/) page regarding authentication, you can use the cookie-based authentication.

If you use Jira cloud check [this documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html) page regarding authentication with tokens.